# How to add an auto updation feature to a private ebook reader android application

Tags: android

I have a private ebook reader application, i want continuously adding new content(article) to that application,i want to add an auto updating feature to that application so that when the user open that application the application get automatically updated if some new contents are added.

Also i want to add the features that the user can get notification that a new version of the application has come when i am adding some new content(article), if he want he can download it, and if he doesn't want the updating version he can reject it also.

Can any body suggest me how to implement this application.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters you want to create a bunch of JSON restful services for the backend.  As far as coordinating you should look into C2DM cloud to device messaging.  Also a lot of apps use UrbanAir for push notification.  I think you really should go for a push capability.